# Android - Hold Activity reference in application-level non-Activity class

Tags: java, android

I have an application class and it holds a reference of MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ......

    private static MyAdapter sMyAdapter;

    public static MyAdapter getMyAdapter() {

        if (sMyAdapter == null) {
            sMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
            MyApplication.setMyAdapter(sMyAdapter);
        }

        return sMyAdapter;
    }

    public static void setMyAdapter(MyAdapter myAdapter) {
        sMyAdapter = myAdapter;
    }

    ......
}
```

MyAdapter class is a customized android adapter class, and the application Context is passed to the Adapter. The application holds a reference of it because it may be used anytime till the application is still running.

The problem is that now I need an Activity Context in the Adapter to start another Activity when some button is clicked because if I use application Context I need to add a Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK which I don't want to because that way the new Activity being started will be running in a new task. I tried a lot with changing launch mode and taskAffinity but either new issues came up or the Activity will be running in a new task.

So I am thinking to hold an Activity reference which shows the button in the Adapter class, and to avoid memory leak, I came up with the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ......

    @override
    public void onResume() {
        ......
        MyApplication.getMyAdapter().setActivity(this);
        ......
    }

    ......

    @override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ......
        MyApplication.getMyAdapter().setActivity(null);
        ......
    }
}
```

Then in the Adapter class I will use the Activity reference to start another Activity. I tested and this worked fine but the question is would this avoid memory leak and is this a proper way to hold the Activity reference when onResume and release it when onDestroy? Is there any other decent way to achieve my purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would this avoid memory leak

Not really. You `MyApplication` object will still keep a reference to your adapter with all it's 'contents' (further references).

Yes, you've got rid of keeping the destroyed `Activity` around, and you might feel it's okay to keep the adapter because you're 'going to need it again anyways', still this whole construct is a horrible [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and will with certainty introduce new memory leaks and other problems as you develop this further. 
Logically, this adapter is part of an `Activity`, and as the `Activity` 'dies', so should the adapter.

I'm sure there's a reason why you felt you needed that adapter on your application, so I'd post another question asking 'how can I achieve soandso without my application knowing of my adapter'.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. I agree with you that the adapter should align with the activity's life cycle but for now I may need to keep the logic... So I meant would `MyApplication.getMyAdapter().setActivity(null);` avoid memory leak of the Activity?

Comment: @MaxW Yes it will.